# New DDR2 RAM doesn't fit

Tags: memory, motherboard, upgrade, ddr2

Just bought 2 4GB sticks of DDR2 RAM, and they don't fit in my motherboard.
The new sticks are **Komputerbay 240 Pin 800MHz PC2-6400F DDR2 ECC Fully Buffered FB-DIMM Memory Modules** (on the bottom in the picture), and my old sticks are **Geil PC2-8500 DDR2-1066 Memory Modules** (on the top in the picture).
My motherboard is an **ASRock N68C-GS4FX**.
My guess was that the new motherboard required **non-ECC momory**, but I really don't know.
[image: Komputerbay RAM: http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B005HIWD4Q]
Thanks in advance,
Will

Comment: Google is Your Friend! :) http://www.asrock.com/MB/NVIDIA/N68C-GS4%20FX/index.asp?cat=Manual  Found this in 30 seconds. You have the wrong kind.

Comment: Yes, your motherboard only supports non-ECC, un-buffered memory. [Here are the specifications](http://www.asrock.com/mb/NVIDIA/N68C-GS4%20FX/?cat=Specifications) for your motherboard.

Comment: if they dont fit, they are wrong, always. take that as life law.

Comment: The lower label is funny. **Unbufffered** 240 pin **unbuffered** dual in-line memory module. They are making very sure it is not registered memory. :)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you bought Fully Buffered DDR2, which is not compatible with DDR2 slots.

If you need further information, you can start with [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_Buffered_DIMM)

> 240-pin DDR2 FB-DIMMs are notched differently from conventional 240-pin DDR2 DIMMs. As a result, those two DIMM types are neither mechanically nor electrically compatible.

Comment: also [referenced in Wikipedia here regarding DDR2 specifically and FB (fully-buffered) RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM#Relative_speed_comparison_between_similar_modules). Also learned this the hard way...

Answer (score 0):

If you somehow ended up with a boatload of the Fully Buffered DDR2 RAM (different architecture than standard DDR2) you might want to consider purchasing a used HP XW6400 Workstation Computer - around $100-$150 refurbished on eBay.  They take the Fully Buffered ECC Memory and Max out at 16gb. Makes for a superfast desktop replacement PC, faster than anything I've seen new if you get one with a Quadcore.

Comment: Your answer is good, i personally avoid to speak about money or prices because they go out to date pretty soon. fix it and i'll upvote.